# What terms or concepts are used to describe the morning metabolic phenomenon involving glucocorticoids, glucose, and blood pressure?

Tags: metabolism, blood-pressure, diabetes-mellitus

A recent [conference report](https://www.webmd.com/hypertension-high-blood-pressure/news/20071106/vaccine-lowers-blood-pressure) described using a vaccine-based strategy to blunt a surge of high blood pressure that occurs between 5 and 8 a.m.  Apparently most heart attacks and strokes occur during this period, which makes this of special importance.  Presumably this ties in with preceding work showing that ordinary blood pressure medication is more effective when taken in the evening.

When I read about the "[dawn phenomenon](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3836163/)" (reduced glucose tolerance in type II diabetics) it is often treated in isolation.  Because glucocorticoids are a factor in the dawn phenomenon, it makes sense they could be involved in raising blood pressure during the same period.

This makes me wonder how much more I have missed.  There seems to be something *special* about the morning period in metabolism, something deserving of some name as fundamental as "sleep".  Yet I don't have one to use, and I don't know why it evolved, how its timing is determined, what its advantage is, whether it correlates with worker productivity, whether early risers and late risers and night shift workers have this period at the same time and so on.  Medical labs typically open at 7:30 a.m. - do they reference the time in relation to any of these phenomena?

Thus the question: **what terms or concepts would you suggest to help someone research and pull together existing knowledge about the metabolic changes that occur in the morning?**

Comment: *Hypoglicemia* is a rather common condition - often pronounced in the morning, but also not uncommon in the late afternoon (hence snacking), and particularly common in small children: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoglycemia

Answer (score 1):

Morning surge, Prewaking surge, Sleep-trough surge, Rising surge.

Example of article using the terms:
"Morning Surge in Blood Pressure and Cardiovascular Risk"
https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/full/10.1161/HYPERTENSIONAHA.110.157149

This one is interesting in that it lists other articles and the term they used for the period you are looking for.